# How can I set a particular member of an inner templated class according to different specializations?

Tags: c++, templates

In terms of specializing an inner templated class of an outer non-templated class, I know that the following is possible (taken from another SO question):

```
struct X
{
    template <typename T>
    class Y
    {};
 };
template<>
class X::Y<double>{
};
```

However, what if I'd like to only set the member of a specialization of the inner class? Is it possible in any way? The following attempt doesn't compile:

```
struct C {

    template <typename T>
    struct Inner {
        static const int x;
    };
};

C::Inner<int>::x = 30;
C::Inner<double>::x = 40;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct syntax:

```
template <>
const int C::Inner<int>::x = 30;

template <>
const int C::Inner<double>::x = 40;
```